# Close Question - Very Low Quality with Bounty

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, bounties

I've came across a question that IMO doesn't have the minimum requirements to stay open. The OP didn't show any efforts to solve the problem and it's also unclear and broad.
I've tried to vote close but it seems that questions with a bounty cannot be closed.

Why not?

[Facebook Android: share image AND link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902237/facebook-android-share-image-and-link)